# Firefox scrolls to top of page when entering data to form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I'am entering data to form which is on the bottom of the page after key hitting page scrolls to top. This is page with this form http://inmed.brandsites.pl/konfigurator/ and it happens when I am trying to complete data in square with title "Osoba zamawiająca". Any ideas why is it so happen?

Comment: Can you show us the relevant parts of your code that may be causing the problem?

Comment: Followed your link and tried it, but it didn't scroll to the top (using Chrome).

Comment: Using Firefox V17 and I do get this error

Comment: It's strange but there no code that causes problem. It's simple form. I don't know why it is so happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a function that handles `onclick` event and returns false or `preventdefault`.

Comment: That's no onclick problem. Problem starts when I am pressing a key inside input text. I can't do preventdefault.